# Как допилить регулярное выражение, что бы разделять предложения?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Сейчас я могу разделять свои предложения  по ., !, ? или переносу строки, но если 2 предложения разделены точкой, но между ними нет пробела, это выражения не работает. Не могу понять, как дополнить его на разделение предложений даже без пробела?

```
[A-Z].*?[.!?](?=\s|$)
```

пр. предложения: Первое предложение.Второе предложение.

Comment: Просто убрать хвост.

Comment: это не помогает

Comment: Что значит не помогает? Qwertiy вот попробовал и ему помогло

Comment: Ну как-бы у вас начало англ., а вы ищите русские буквы? Странно, как-то.

Answer (score -1):

Может символ пробела просто добавить в группу символов, которые могут быть в предложении?

```
[А-я ]*[!.?]
```

Comment: Ерунда полнейшая.

Answer (score -2):

Надо просто убрать хвост:

```
[A-Z].*?[.!?]
```